# shoppingcart page html forms design

Tags: html, forms, shopping-cart

while designing the template for a shoppingcart view,I used a loop to create a list of items in the cart to be displayed .I also want to provide remove buttons to enable the user to remove each item from the cart.The html came out to be like this

here in the below html code,in /books/removefromcart/91 , 91 is the shoppingcart id.
The cartitemid represents the item's id.

Is this bad style to create one form for each list item?Which is the correct way?

```
<form action="/books/removefromcart/91" method="POST" > 
  <li>1. mastering java  1 copies 
<input type="hidden" name="cartitemId" value="94"/> 
<input type="submit" value="remove"/>              
</li>                   
</form>

<form action="/books/removefromcart/91" method="POST" > 
<li>2. mastering python 2 copies 
<input type="hidden" name="cartitemId" value="93"/> 
<input type="submit" value="remove"/>              
</li>                   
</form>

<form action="/books/removefromcart/91" method="POST" > 
<li>3. mastering ruby 1 copies 
<input type="hidden" name="cartitemId" value="92"/> 
 <input type="submit" value="remove"/>             
 </li>                  
</form>
..
<!--a form for adding item to cart -->
<form action="/books/addtocart/43" method="POST">
  <label for="quantity">Number of Copies:</label>               
<select id="quantity" name="quantity"> 
<option selected="" value="1">1</option> 
<option value="2">2</option> 
<option value="3">3</option>
...
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="91"/> 
<input type="submit" value="AddToCart" />  
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On each button of update/remove call one javascript function and pass that product value to that function...and then you can process on it...

e.g: ---

```
<input type="button" OnSubmit="remove('91');" value="Remove" />


function remove(id)
{

    $.ajax({
                                url: 'yourpage.aspx,
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: 'prodid='+id,
                                success: function(response) {
                                    /*your code for success goes here */
                                }
                            });
}
```